# Reading csv and write it into xml file including empty csv fields

Tags: java

Please find the code that i written.
My csv fields are: thiru, 1234, , hyd

```
while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
    String curValue = String.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextElement());
    System.out.println("Next element is : " + curValue);
}
```

Output:

```
thiru
1234
hyd.
```

Required output:

```
thiru
1234

hyd
```

please any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Add [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) to your project and use the [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class:

```
String input = "thiru, 1234, , hyd";

for (String s : Splitter.on(',').trimResults().split(input)) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```